# PWA2APK on play store is still showing url bar at top

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, progressive-web-apps

I created a progressive web app, and it works perfectly. It prompts for installation and it saves the link on the android home and it shows no url address bar.

Then I used PWA2APK (https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/) to create an APK and deploy on play store.

In one website I use to apk one is teleporting to other page and second is to the main page
users app and delivery app

since it is recommended to use .well-known with only one name which is assetlinks.json
can i do this to add two pwatoapk app?

````
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "xyz.appmaker.xxxxx",
        "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA","BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB"]
    }
  }
]
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "xyz.appmaker.xxxx",
        "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA","BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB"]
    }
  }
]

which one is right?

[{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "xyz.appmaker.xxxx",
      ""sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA","BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB"]
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "xyz.appmaker.xxxx",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA","BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB"]
    }
  }
}]```
````

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: Yes, back then it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have two SHA keys in your ./well-known/assetlinks.json, they are separated by a comma, use only one of them.  You can see the same issue is here [PWA2APK on play store is still showing url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879894/pwa2apk-on-play-store-is-still-showing-url/56575187#56575187)

So change from this

```
  "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA","BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB"]
```

to

```
  "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA"]
```

Also check that if you are having google manage your keystore to use their SHA as they resign your app with a new key. https://youtu.be/Ppzjg6uzWt8?t=180