# Problems when updating PWA app built with PWA2APK on Google Play

Tags: reactjs, google-play, apk, progressive-web-apps, android-app-bundle

I have used PWA2APK to upload the first version of my React app to Google Play. It worked great. But every time I try to update the app by uploading a new version, I get the following:

```
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
SHA1: *******************
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: **********************
Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name ****(name_of_previous_version)****.
You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1.
```

Here's the steps I've been following:

**For the first version**: paste url to PWA2APK and download APK file. change well-know directory with the SHA from Google Play. Upload first version APK to Google Play. All is good.

**Then, when I need to release a newer version of the app**: change all of my files, paste url to PWA2APK. Change well-know file again (*which this time has a new package_name*).  Download APK and try to upload to Google Play. That's when the above error shows.

1. Am I following the right procedure?
2. Should I just change the package_name to be the same as the previous version?
3. Does the downloaded APK file need to have its name changed before being uploaded to Google Play?

And by the way, The Google Play console tells me that Google is managing my app signing key.

Answer (score 0):

1. The package name needs to be exactly the same as the previous versions
2. Your app needs to be signed as a release app and and have the same signing certificate used to sign it.

Seeing that you are using an online converter, this is probably the problem as it is generating you different package names and certificates.